# How to let mocha work with tamejs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, tamejs

I want to use tamejs to write mocha tests, but mocha doesn't support it by default.

Is there any way to let mocha work with tamejs? I don't want to write `.tjs` files and compiling them into `.js` each time before running tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an external compiler in mocha with `--compilers` option

> --compilers
>
> coffee-script is no longer supported out of the box. CS and similar transpilers may be used by mapping the file extensions (for use with –watch) and the module name. For example --compilers coffee:coffee-script.

So, create `mocha.opts` in your app/tests path and add :

```
--compilers tjs:tamejs
```

Then every extension `.tjs` will be compiled automatically when starting mocha

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found the generated js file from tjs can't work with mocha, see https://github.com/maxtaco/tamejs/issues/30